# Can I connect Red Hat Developer Studio with Red Hat Decision Manager?

Tags: redhat-brms

Is there any way to connect RH Dev Studio with Red Hat Decision Manager? What is the ideal process to develop rule and keep the rules in sync in both local env and RD DM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem in hand, you would want to maintain the code on an external repo - `git`, from which you can sync the code. Once the code is maintained on Git, you can use the repo to import a synced project.

As of now, there is no default way of maintaining an external `git` repository. Red Hat is working on getting this feature up and running with *DM/PAM 7.2*. So we need to wait for that to come.

However, following may help you do what you're inteding:

#### Download code and maintain Git repo manually.

You could download the DM repo/project from Decision Central and maintain a Git repo with your local changes, that can allow you to sync the changes but it requires to be done manually.

#### Create a hook in the Git repo of DM.

This could be a way to automatically send the changes to Git on every commit. You could create a hook from within the `.niogit`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rupesh. This helps.